# Xubuntu 16.04 external monitor

Tags: xubuntu, multiple-monitors, monitor

Ok, my first question here is simple:

I have xubuntu 16.04 LTS on Laptop X86_64. The laptop can handle ubuntu xenial xerus to but I like xubuntu. It works like a CPU because I link It to a big external monitor, and is linked to a huge sound box. I can tun off the laptop monitor, but I always forget how to turn It off and close It, repeat close the screen of the laptop; without turn off the external monitor to. How can I do It?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer after ask here in a Brazilian Blog, it is in Portuguese, but has, translate button I think so... Edivaldo's blog.  Worked on my new xubuntu 16.04. laptop.
"Como configurar o Ubuntu para desligar quando a tampa do Laptop for fechada:
2016 - EdivaldoLinux
Se você usa o Ubuntu ou um sistema derivado dele e quer mudar o comportamento do sistema quando a tampa do laptop for fechada, veja aqui como fazer.
desligar-laptop
Normalmente, ao baixar a tampa de um laptop ele entra em hibernação, mas nem sempre esse é o comportamento que usuário quer. Por exemplo, o sistema também pode ser desligado. Se você ainda não sabe como configurar isso, acompanhe esse tutorial e descubra.
Como configurar o Ubuntu para desligar quando a tampa do Laptop for fechada

Para configurar o Ubuntu para desligar quando a tampa do Laptop for fechada, você pode abrir as “Configurações do sistema” e no item “Energia”, colocar o campo “Quando a tampa for fechada” como Desligar. Alternativamente, você pode optar por “Suspender” ou “Não fazer nada. Mas se preferir fazer isso no arquivo de configuração, faça o seguinte:
Passo 1. Abra um terminal (Usando o Dash ou pressionando as teclas CTRL+ALT+T)
Passo 2. Execute o comando abaixo para abrir o arquivo de configuração via editor de textos Gedit:

sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf

Passo 3. Encontre a linha #HandleLidSwitch=suspend, remova o símbolo # e mude-a para o comportamento correspondente ao que deseja usar. Por exemplo, para desligar o computador quando a tampa for fechada, deixe assim:

HandleLidSwitch=poweroff

Passo 4. Para hibernar o computador quando a tampa for fechada, deixe assim:

HandleLidSwitch=hibernate

Passo 5. Para não fazer nada, use isso:

HandleLidSwitch=ignore

Passo 6. Salve o arquivo e feche-o.
Passo 7. Execute o comando abaixo ou simplesmente reinicie o computador, para aplicar as alterações;

sudo restart systemd-logind

Pronto! Agora você já pode usar seu equipamento com mais tranquilidade, sem ficar se preocupando com seus documentos"

It is not scan or advertising. I needed the answer and found It, ok?

My best regards to all.

"